# JS-grid working example required

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsgrid

i am new working with jsgrid ,went through documentation but i'm unable to load data .. can any one please provide a working example of jsgrid with ajax calls.. i wanted to perform loaddata on service call, edit delete by making a service call.....
    Kindly donot mark negative ,asking for help after researching a lot and    things didnot work

Answer (score 0):

Here are completely working js-grid examples for different back-ends:

- PHP - https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-php
- ASP.NET WebAPI - https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-webapi
- Express (NodeJS) - https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-express
- Ruby on Rail - https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-rails
- Django (Python) - https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-django

Taken from http://js-grid.com/samples/

Comment: could you specify technologies?

Comment: i need examples for java backends please... for CRUD operations with dynamic data

Comment: @tabalin can u provide solution at earliest plz